# Google App Engine not autoscaling php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, autoscaling

I have a project running on App Engine, with PHP, and it's [not autoscaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDY7K.png)

My `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
threadsafe: true
env_variables:
  APP_KEY: 'base64:*****'
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  DB_DATABASE: animes
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_PASSWORD: ******
  DB_SOCKET: '/cloudsql/*******'
  DB_USERNAME: root
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 20
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Your instances will scale up when you reach that [target CPU utilization](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling). Are you reaching it? The image shows number of requests, not CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your ["target_ultilization" configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml#automatic_scaling) that you need to be using 0.5 (50%) of your CPUs before scaling up.