# How do I change max and min latency in my App Engine?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, request, autoscaling, latency

I have a project running on App Engine, with PHP, and it's [not autoscaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDY7K.png)

My `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php
api_version: '1.0'
env: flexible
threadsafe: true
env_variables:
  APP_KEY: 'base64:*****'
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  CACHE_DRIVER: database
  DB_DATABASE: animes
  DB_HOST: localhost
  DB_PASSWORD: ******
  DB_SOCKET: '/cloudsql/*******'
  DB_USERNAME: root
  SESSION_DRIVER: database
  STORAGE_DIR: /tmp
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  max_num_instances: 20
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
```

Do I need that autoscaling with latency or count of requests? Is it possible?

I try setting max_pending_latency and min_pending_latency in my app.yaml, but have this error:

```
automatic_scaling:
  max_pending_latency: 30ms
  min_pending_latency: 15ms
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 20
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
```

Return of gcloud app deploy

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: VM-based automatic scaling should NOT 
have the following parameter(s): [min_pending_latency, max_pending_latency]
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: 'VM-based automatic scaling should NOT have the following parameter(s):
      [min_pending_latency, max_pending_latency]'
    field: version.automatic_scaling
```

Comment: You can't use `min_pending_latency` in Flexible, if you are referring to [these values](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/config/appref#scaling_elements). In Flexible you can only scale based on CPU usage (automatic scaling) , as you have, and as it was explained in [another question you have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915078/google-app-engine-not-autoscaling-php), or use manual scaling.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine not autoscaling php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915078/google-app-engine-not-autoscaling-php)

Comment: Please remember to upvote and/or accept an answer if it helps you resolve your issue or understand your issue. That's to help future Stackoverflow users who sees this question.

Comment: Sorry because this "Possible duplicate of Google App Engine not autoscaling php", my first time

Comment: "You can't use min_pending_latency in Flexible, if you are referring to these values. In Flexible you can only scale based on CPU usage (automatic scaling) , as you have, and as it was explained in another question you have, or use manual scaling.". I need change my app.yaml, how do I this?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/reference/app-yaml) that App Engine Flex do not use max/min latency for scaling; all scaling decision is based on CPU usage.

Comment: So it's impossible for me to be able to set a latency for autoscaling? Because my application does not reach 40%, but the latency is in 2 minutes.

Comment: Correct. Unless you use GAE Standard. Also, I am unsure how another instance would help if the current instance are not fully utilized yet. CPU is CPU regardless or whether it came from this instance or another. I suspect there might be something else you can do to reduce the latency (it depends on what you are doing).

A good way to test this is to use manual scaling and test it with a couple of instance and see if the latency decreases by throwing additional instances at it. I don't think it would, but it's worth a try if you want to see it.